# Ecto build_assoc/3 does not match defined foreign key?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have the following two models, `User` and `Post`. I am trying to create a post with a foreign key relation to a user.

My schemas:

```
@primary_key {:id, :binary_id, autogenerate: true}
schema "accounts_users" do
  field :username, :string
  field :email, :string
  field :password_hash, :string
  field :password, :string, virtual: true
  has_many :posts, Udia.Logs.Post

  timestamps(type: :utc_datetime)
end


@primary_key {:id, :binary_id, autogenerate: true}
schema "logs_posts" do
  field :title, :string
  field :content, :string
  belongs_to :creator, Udia.Accounts.User

  timestamps(type: :utc_datetime)
end
```

My post creation method:

```
def create_post(user, attrs \\ %{}) do
  user
  |> Ecto.build_assoc(:posts, attrs)
  |> post_changeset(attrs)
  |> Repo.insert()
end

defp post_changeset(%Post{} = post, attrs) do
  IO.inspect post
  post
  |> cast(attrs, [:title, :content])
  |> validate_required([:title, :content])
end
```

When I create my association and I inspect the post, I expect `creator_id` to be set to the `user_id`, however this is what I see instead:

```
%{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built, logs_posts>,
  __struct__: Udia.Logs.Post, content: some content,
  creator: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :creator is not loaded>,
  creator_id: nil, id: nil, inserted_at: nil, title: some title,
  updated_at: nil, user_id: 9400d72e-9042-4f83-a0f4-0ef247358690}
```

Why is the User foreign key id not matching the schema defined in Post?

Comment: Try adding `foreign_key` to the `has_many`: `has_many :posts, Udia.Logs.Post, foreign_key: :creator_id`.

Answer (score 3):

Just solved it, I needed to update my schemas to the following:

```
@primary_key {:id, :binary_id, autogenerate: true}
schema "accounts_users" do
  field :username, :string
  field :email, :string
  field :password_hash, :string
  field :password, :string, virtual: true

  # explicitly specify creator_id
  has_many :posts, Udia.Logs.Post, foreign_key: :creator_id

  timestamps(type: :utc_datetime)
end

@primary_key {:id, :binary_id, autogenerate: true}
schema "logs_posts" do
  field :title, :string
  field :content, :string

  # explicitly specify binary_id
  belongs_to :creator, Udia.Accounts.User, type: :binary_id

  timestamps(type: :utc_datetime)
end
```

Comment: Do you also have the `@foreign_key_type :binary_id` module attribute set?
Edit: Sorry, just saw there is `type: :binary_id` on the `belongs_to`.